# Angular using MSAL Service authentication using username and password

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am working on one project with angular 7, we have already SSO but I need to use Microsoft Graphs. Right now I am trying with `MSAL (@azure/msal-angular)` but I can not find the way for make login with MSAL using only `@username` and `@password`.

```
 MsalModule.forRoot({
 clientID: "1231231-1212-4566-2345-fssfr34fsdf" })
```

Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send the username/password in an API call to get an authentication token.  Microsoft Graph doesn't support this.

If you are ok with authenticating without user context i.e. application only context, then the client_credential flow is probably your best bet. You authenticate with an app id and secret.

[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)